# How do I remove the 'RSS Feeds' folder from Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, outlook-web-access

By default, Outlook 2010 creates an "RSS Feeds" folder which cannot be deleted in the usual way you would delete a folder.

[image]

I want to remove the folder, so I read [How to Remove RSS Support from Outlook](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/how-to-remove-rss-support-from-outlook/) and discovered the [MFCMapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) gem of a utility.  I followed the instructions in the section "Delete the RSS folder using MFCMAPI" section, and was able to remove the folder from Outlook.

However, the "RSS Feeds" folder now shows in the "Deleted Items" folder in Outlook Web Access (OWA) and also on my mobile devices, but *not* in Outlook.  In OWA I attempted a right-click and delete, but I am told that folder cannot be deleted.  I poked around my OST file (I am running in cached exchange mode) using again using MFCMapi to see if I could find the folder but I do not see it.  Finally I created a new Outlook profile in which I do *not* cache messages, so I could get a "live" look at the server and attempt to see the folder and delete it that way, but it still did not show.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use MFCMAPI again, does it show it under Deleted Items?

Comment: @techie007 - Nope, that's what I was saying above, that when I poked around again using MFCMapi it did not exist (under Deleted Items or anywhere that I could find.)

Comment: Weird, do you have Admin access to the Exchange server?

Comment: @techie007 - What does the admin have to do to resolve this?

Comment: @techie007 - You got me all excited thinking you had something for the admin to do but then you disappeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the RSS Feeds folder by modifying the registry:

**Outlook 2013**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\RSS
DWORD: Disable
Value: 1
```

**Outlook 2010**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Options\RSS
DWORD: Disable
Value: 1
```

**This will just disable RSS functionality, but doesn't remove the RSS folder**. Any PSTs created after you enable this registry will not include the RSS folder.

To remove the the RSS folder from your current PST, you have to use the MAPI editor - MFCMAPI Editor: http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com

You should backup your PST then hide the RSS folder (better than delete option) - here you can find a step-by-step tutorial, with screenshots:

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/delete-outlooks-default-folders/

Comment: I've been successful using MFCMAPI to remove the RSS folder on my local OST copy but it does not replicate that change to the server.  I am wondering if, like you said, I made this registry change and then set up a totally new account (blank server-side) if the RSS folder would not exist at all...

Comment: This is a local group policy change, basically you disabled the RSS feature locally. For server side the group policy must be changed.