# How do I remove 'RSS Feeds' folder without downloading software?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm aware of [this similar question for Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/q/689231/993453), but I covet a more effortless solution than [downloading software](https://superuser.com/a/782932/993453).

As you can see beneath, the 'Delete Folder' option is greyed out and unavailable. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delete option is grey out because RSS folder is a default system folder in Outlook client. It cannot be deleted just like you cannot delete Outbox or Draft folder.

The available option is to use MFCMapi tool.

You can refer to the reply of our MVP in this thread to Hide or Delete Outlook's Default Folders:
[Outlook Navigation Pane](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e2060279-d114-465e-a5d0-bf77c0861d53/outlook-navigation-pane?forum=outlook)